# image_picker Cancel: Navigation.pop inside Widget builder for Flutter

Tags: build, flutter, widget, picker, navigator

I have the following issue in my Flutter App:

For the `image_picker` Cancel-button to work properly, I needed to be able to Navigate.pop() at the moment the user presses the Cancel-button inside the [image_picker Plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker).

The main question for this image_picker-Cancel issue is: How can I navigate back (i.e. `Navigator.pop(context)`) inside a builder of a Widget ?

The following throws an error:

```dart
  Widget _cancelBtnPressedWidget(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
```

I know a Widget is supposed to `return` something. Therefore is it possible to pseudo-return something - but actually keep the Navigator.pop() as the main action inside the Widget ??? (and best, automatically invoked without extra user-interaction)...

From the above code, the error sais:

```dart
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY ANIMATION LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown while notifying status listeners for AnimationController:
flutter: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
flutter: This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the
flutter: process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase
flutter: only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework
flutter: builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built.
flutter: Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
flutter: The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
flutter:   Overlay-[LabeledGlobalKey<OverlayState>#b5c98](state: OverlayState#6a872(entries:
flutter:   [OverlayEntry#cd1e7(opaque: false; maintainState: false), OverlayEntry#43b81(opaque: false;
flutter:   maintainState: true), OverlayEntry#f0b49(opaque: false; maintainState: false),
flutter:   OverlayEntry#b9362(opaque: false; maintainState: true)]))
flutter: The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
flutter:   FutureBuilder<File>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<File>#d3cac)
```

.

Here a more detailed description to where the above requirement comes from :

In fact, I would like to use the Navigator.pop() as soon as the user presses the cancel-Button as for a [`image_picker` Plugin](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker) usage.

I realised that the `snapshot.hashCode`-change is one way to detect the Cancel-Button from being pressed by the user. Therefore if the user presses that Cancel-button, I would like to do no more than navigate.pop back to where I came from ;)... I don't want to show anymore or keep the user inside a Widget, but immediately return back to the view that originally Navigate.pushed.

Here is the image-picker part that does the image-finding - and the Cancel-treatment (i.e. call of `_cancelBtnPressedWidget`-Widget).

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

File _imageFile;
bool _pickImage = true;
int _hashy = 0;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  if (_pickImage) {
    return FutureBuilder<File>(
      future: ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<File> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          _pickImage = false;
          _imageFile = snapshot.data;
          return _showImage(snapshot.data);
        } else {
          // when cancel is pressed, the hashCode changes...
          if ((_hashy != 0) && (snapshot.hashCode != _hashy)) {
            // when cancel pressed
            return _cancelBtnPressedWidget(context);
          }
          _hashy = snapshot.hashCode;
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text('no image picker available'),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  } else {
    return _showImage(_imageFile);
  }
}
```

```dart
Widget _cancelBtnPressedWidget(BuildContext context) {
  // requires a return ..... How to overcome this requirement ????
  Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

```dart
Widget _showImage(File imgFile) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Stack(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart,
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            left: 0.0,
            bottom: 0.0,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Center(
              child: imgFile == null
                  ? Text('No image selected.')
                  : Image.file(imgFile),
            ),
          ),
         // more stacks ... not important here....
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Of course, inside pubspec.yaml you add the necessary dependency:

```dart
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  image_picker: ^0.5.0+3
```

Add-on:

I tried to add a confirmation-dialog (i.e. to ask the user "Do you really want to cancel").

Now, the above error is gone. However, now the `image_picker` keeps popping up again and again...overwriting this dialog.

What am I still doing wrong her ??

```dart
Widget _cancelBtnPressedWidget(BuildContext context) {
  return AlertDialog(
    title: Text('Camera Alert'),
    content: Text('Are you sure you want to cancel ?'),
    actions: <Widget>[
      FlatButton(
        child: Text('Close'),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      )
    ],
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found an answer:

Indeed, I was able to place a confirmation-dialog and there I was able to place the necessary `return Widget`.

Now the Cancel for the image_picker is working as expected !

Here is the entire Code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class MyImagePickerView extends StatefulWidget {
  _MyImagePickerViewState createState() => _MyImagePickerViewState();
}

class _MyImagePickerViewState extends State<MyImagePickerView> {
  File _imageFile;
  bool _pickImage = true;
  int _hashy = 0;
  bool _cancelPressed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_pickImage) {
      return FutureBuilder<File>(
        future: ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<File> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            _pickImage = false;
            _imageFile = snapshot.data;
            return _showImage(snapshot.data);
          } else {
            // when cancel is pressed, the hashCode changes...
            if ((_hashy != 0) && (snapshot.hashCode != _hashy)) {
              // when cancel pressed
              return _cancelBtnPressedWidget(context);
            }
            _hashy = snapshot.hashCode;
            return Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: Text('no image picker available'),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      );
    } else {
      if (_cancelPressed) {
        return _showAlert();
      } else {
        return _showImage(_imageFile);
      }
    }
  }

  Widget _cancelBtnPressedWidget(BuildContext context) {
    _cancelPressed = true;
    _pickImage = false;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Press button to start.'),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _showImage(File imgFile) {
    StateContainerState container = StateContainer.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topStart,
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              left: 0.0,
              bottom: 0.0,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: Center(
                child: imgFile == null
                    ? Text('No image selected.')
                    : Image.file(imgFile),
              ),
            ),
            // more stacks ... not important here....
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _showAlert() {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Camera Alert'),
      content: Text('Are you sure you want to cancel the Camera ?'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          child: Text('No'),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _pickImage = true;
              _cancelPressed = false;
            });
          },
        ),
        FlatButton(
          child: Text('Yes'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it doesn't seem like you are capturing the click at all. For me I would return a button in the `_cancelBtnPressedWidget` and in the onPressed call the pop.

Comment: hmm, I do not want to make the user click twice. (i.e. the Cancel-button is part of the native-plugin I guess) and therefore I would like to bail out of the Widget without adding another extra-button. However, your answer brings me to the idea that I could add some sort of confirmation-dialog and there I could use the `onPressed`-event. Let me try...

Comment: I added the confirmation-dialog idea at the bottom of my original question. However, it still does not work since this `image_picker` keeps overwriting the  dialog. (i.e. the dialog only crops up for a short glimpse and disappears again being overwritten by the camera-plugin). What could I do else to keep the dialog on top of the view ? Thank you for any hint on this...

Comment: Ah I see, I'm not very familiar with that plugin.  But maybe try this one instead? https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/multi_image_picker#-readme-tab-